# regex for capturing path from a string with optional character ~ (perl|awk|sed|..)

Tags: regex, perl, path

I want to match everything between first and last slash `/` including optional `~` before first slash.

I used this for the first part:

```
echo ~~a~/dir1/di r2/b.c \
| perl -pe 's/[^\/]*(\/.*\/).*/\1/'
```

which produces `/dir1/di r2/`.

This match includes the tilde:

`perl -pe 's/`**.***`(`**~**`\/.*\/).*/\1/'`

but adding `?` for optional character doesn't seem to work like in these cases:

`perl -pe 's/`**.***`(`**~?**`\/.*\/).*/\1/'` -> `/di r2/`
`perl -pe 's/`**.***`(`**(?:~)**`\/.*\/).*/\1/'` -> `~~a/dir1/di r2/b.c`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to your second set of examples, you want to include the slash in the capture -- is that correct?  See my answer.  If not, that is fixed by merely moving capturing parenthesis outside.

Comment: What if there are no slashes, or only one?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, in case of no slashes it should return empty string, and in case of one `/` it should return `/` with tilde if present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the desired output right, this works for me with or without tilde

```
echo "path /d1/d2/43a/" | perl -nE 'm{ ( ~? (?: /.*/ | /) ) }x; say "$1"'
```

Prints

```
/d1/d2/43a/
```

Same Perl code, with a tilde before the first slash in the input

```
echo "path ~/d1/d2/43a/" | perl -nE 'm{ ( ~? (?: /.*/ | /) ) }x; say "$1"'
```

prints

```
~/d1/d2/43a/
```

**Notes**    Use of `/1` in the substitution is deprecated. Use `$1` instead.  With `{}` for the delimiters we don't have to escape `/`, making it more readable (while with delimiters other than `//` we can't leave out `m` in front). Otherwise the same works when using `/` for delimiter and then escaping it inside.

---

**Update**

To also catch a lone `~/` (or `/`), the simplest change was to add that explicitly, `/.*/ | /`. In order to capture the (optinal) `~` in both cases there is a (non-capturing) grouping around this.  Removed `-w` flag so no warnings are issued when the input string has no slashes at all, but only an empty line is printed.

Comment: It should not match anything before first slash (or tilda followed by slash), so asdf /path/.file -> "/path/", or asdf ~/path/.file -> "~/path/"

Comment: @Radivarig  The `/m` based code works that way -- I forgot to adjust in the substitution, which has the problem because of greedy `.*` preceding an optional item.  Will put it back when fixed.

Comment: Indeed `/m` does match it. Just one thing, for a single slash it complains about `uninitialized value $1`. `~/.file` should return `~/`

Comment: @Radivarig  Right, I didn't think of a lone slash.  Added a simple fix to include that, which needed an extra (non-capturing) grouping to get the tilde in both cases as well.  Also changed the delimiter since now `|` _is_ used inside regex.

Comment: @Radivarig  There is one note, or a modification, to add:  If there are no slashes at all my code will print a warning, since it attempts to actually _use_ the capture (which there isn't, without a slash).  The warnings are, however, specifically enforced by `-w` flag, so if you drop that there will be no warnings when there's no match (slash), just an empty string printed.  Let me know if you think that this is better generally so I remove `-w` from the answer.

Comment: Yes, that would be better. No match, no path string.

Comment: @Radivarig  Adjusted the answer.  (Testing _was_ done with `-w` though.)  One of the (clean and simple) ways around greedy-*-match followed by optional item is to use negative lookaheads, I think.  I will add that if/when I find time to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

### Original requirements

#### File `data`

```
~~a~/dir1/di r2/b.c
/dir1/di r2/z.y
~/dir1/di r3/p.q
gobbledegook~/name/more/still/more/notwanted.c
xxx~//yyy
```

#### Script

```
perl -ple 's%(?:^.*?)((?:^|~)/.*/).*%$1%' data
```

#### Example output

```
~/dir1/di r2/
/dir1/di r2/
~/dir1/di r3/
~/name/more/still/more/
~//
```

Is that what you needed?

#### Dissecting the regex

```
s%(?:^.*?)((?:^|~)/.*/).*%$1%
```

The first part, `(?:^.*?)` is a non-capturing non-greedy match for an arbitrary sequence of characters at the start of the line.

The second part, `((?:^|~)/.*/)`, is a capturing expression that contains a non-capturing term that matches at the start of a line, or a tilde, followed by a slash and a greedy anything up to the last slash on the line.

The trailing `.*` matches everything after the second part.

The replacement is simply what was captured; the rest is Perl being Perl.

---

### Revised requirements

The original problem statement was incomplete, it seems.  Apparently:

> for single slash it should output just `/` (with accompanying tilde if present). For no slashes preferably empty string as there is no match. … And for this case `~a b/c/d.f` it returns full string; instead it should return `/c/`.

So, here is a revised script to deal with the special extra cases (what happened to 'learning how to fish'?).  The `~a b/c/d.f` case was a missing `?` qualifier on a 'start of string or tilde' grouping.

#### Revised `data` file

```
~~a~/dir1/di r2/b.c
/dir1/di r2/z.y
~/dir1/di r3/p.q
gobbledegook~/name/more/still/more/notwanted.c
xxx~//yyy
not-a-slash-in-sight
just-the-one/with-extra-info
just-the~/with-more-info
~/one-slash-at-start-with-tilde
/one-slash-at-start-without-tilde
~a b/c/d.f
```

#### Revised script

```
perl -ple 's%^[^/]*$%%; s%(?:^[^/]*?)((?:^|~)?/)[^/]*$%$1%; s%(?:^[^/]*?)((?:^|~)?/.*/).*%$1%' data
```

A mildly modified of the original expression comes last.

The first `s///` looks for lines without any `/` and replaces them with nothing.

The second `s///` looks for lines with a slash, possibly preceded by tilde or start of line, followed by non-slashes to end of line with the optional tilde and the slash.

The output of the first two in event of a match does not match the third `s///`.

#### Revised output

```
~/dir1/di r2/
/dir1/di r2/
~/dir1/di r3/
~/name/more/still/more/
~//

/
~/
~/
/
/c/
```

Comment: Almost, for single slash it should output just `/` (with accompanying tilde if present). For no slashes preferably empty string as there is no match, but I check for existence of directory so the latter is not relevant that much.

Comment: Your sample inputs and output do not demonstrate or mention such a refinement.  Please don't go modifying your requirements after you get answers — ask the whole question from the beginning.  I'll work on a solution for that, but … no fair changing the rules.

Comment: For this case `~a b/c/d.f` it returns full string, instead it should return `/c/`

Comment: I didn't explicitly mention the case of a single slash, but I stated and gave an example input of a `path` which would imply that it can have an arbitrary positive number of slashes.

Comment: All of this just goes to show that you should specify the complete requirements from the start.  Regexes are a balancing game — what matches vs what the other possible inputs could be.  I'll work on the `~a b/c/d.f` example — though I don't see an example equivalent to that in the question.  I see exactly one input in the question.

Comment: I object to your stance and find it inappropriate. As a matter of fact a single slash is both the first and the last one in a string, so the case is included in the original requirement. I do not see why commenting on it additionally as a clarification could be an issue, even if it was not mentioned.

Comment: I especially object the need for `was incomplete` `it seems` `apparently` and mostly `what happened to 'learning how to fish'?`. You are not obligated to answer my question and I did not ask for someone to "fish" instead of me, I asked "What am I doing wrong?" so to put it in your fishy jargon I asked "Why is the described way of my fishing not resulting in an expected fish". This has been very unpleasant and I suggest and would appreciate if you'd reconsider the attitude in providing answers.

Comment: You're allowed to object; I'm allowed to object.  Your question still shows precisely one sample input (`~~a~/dir1/di r2/b.c`) and the desired output, and mentions that the `~` before the first slash is optional.  The other requirements (single slashes, no slashes) have been added later — though the `~a b/c/d.f` variant was a mistake in my original answer.  The trouble was that came on top of the rest of the 'chameleon question' changes — and chameleon questions are definitely not popular.  You need to ask more complete questions — single sample inputs and outputs won't deal with all variants.